# Websphere MQ issue

Tags: ibm-mq

Recently I got an application request :
A sends orders to T via MQ. The messages sent by A use CCSID 500.
While recieving the order at T end most of the orders are in CCSID 500 format. But some of the orders have their CCSID changed to 1047.
When this is the case A-T interface stops and the orders have to be manually inserted into the databse.
Can you advise us under what circumstances this CCSID could change? And is there any configuration changes that could be made either at T or A side to prevent this happening ?

Answer (score 0):

The CCSID is set by the application that does the MQPUT.
When it is left empty then it is filled by the underlyingin MQ installation.
The MQGET application can set a message get option to convert it to a desired CCSID.
There are tables in the appendix of the "application programming reference" in Knowledge center for all possible translations.

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with `MQFMT_STRING` messages, you should be able to use `GMO_CONVERT` so all the messages get converted to the CCSID on the T side.

You may have an issue with missing translation tables on the receiving side. Check in the MQ installation directory `/IBM/WebSphere MQ/conv/table`.

Here's a little note from IBM describing the differences between EBCDIC code pages: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.char/src/tpc/db2z_codeptdiffebcdic.dita

Source: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27005729